# Is there a keyboard shortcut for allowing pop-ups in popular web-browsers?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser, popups

Is there a keyboard shortcut for allowing pop-ups in popular web-browsers?  I'm a Mac user of Chrome and Firefox, but I'm sure Windows users would be interested in answers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Firefox, you can install an extension called PrefBar:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/prefbar/versions/

After installing it, open its preference, and drag the "Popup" option from left column to right, the right click that option to open its "Edit" window. There you can assign a keyboard shortcut.

After you saved all the settings, you can now disable the toolbar from showing and the keyboard shortcut still works.

There are other extensions that can do the same thing, like [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/). But this is the most lightweight extension I can find.

I don't know much about Chrome. Hope someone else could provide a way to do it.

Answer (score -2):

On IE and MS Edge, hold ctrl + alt before clicking a link to allow popups.